# Retrieve list of all Amazon EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How can I retrieve a list of all my instances, aside from using the Access tokens (=the standard way)?

Comment: Open up the EC2 web console? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The only *supported* way to get a list of your instance is to use the DescribeInstances API command (using any of the SDKs or command line tools).

Usually this requires you to use your access keys.  The exception to this is if you are executing the DescribeInstances API command on an EC2 instance.  If so, you can use EC2 Roles to avoid using the access keys.

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation and it said this: https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances
&AUTHPARAMS What about the domainname-part?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what docs you read and what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: How to use those EC2 rules, because it when I go to that link it says it cannot validate the provided access credentials.

Comment: Those roles can only be set in the web console.